# android camera implementation

Tags: android, camera

I am going to implement camera feature for my android app.for this, I searched a lot on internet and found 2 way to implement camera feature

1. design your own camera class using

   `android.view.SurfaceHolder and
   android.view.SurfaceView`

but this approach does look good to me as in this i have to take care of many things which will make my code complex.

2.   I can use intent to call device camera. now again in this , i have 2 option

i ) using `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` and not using `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`

if i dont use `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` I get a thumbnail which is not my actual requirement. i need image larger than this so if I scale this thumbnail, i find low quality image.

if i use `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` I dint get any image on some device like samsung as in

`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)`

I find intent is null . after searching a lot on internet, i found that this is device specific issue. i have Samsung Galaxy with me. and on this i am facing this issue.

i dont want my code to be a device specific code. so can any one tell me how to make my code generic. for your analysis, i am using following code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
                File root = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "myDir" + File.separator)
                if(!root.exists()){
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
                sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName");
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
Uri outputFileUri;
protected void startCameraActivity() {

    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (resultCode) {
    case 0:
        finish();
        break;

    case -1:

        try {
            if(intent != null)
            StoreImage(this, Uri.parse(intent.toURI()),
                    sdImageMainDirectory);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Intent i = new Intent(this,Home.class);
        i.putExtra("url", outputFileUri);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

}
public static void StoreImage(Context mContext, Uri imageLoc, File imageDir) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        bm = Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageLoc);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageDir);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        bm.recycle();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this link: [Capture image using Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032870/how-to-send-captured-image-by-camera-to-a-next-view/8033046#8033046)

This code works fine in all the Samsung devices I have used (like Galaxy S, Galaxy Tab, Galaxy Pro).